# Is setting image src to base64 synchronous?

Tags: javascript, html

When setting a `HTMLImageElement`'s `src` property to a URL typically you need to listen to the 'load' event before getting `width` or passing to `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` ect.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = URL;
image.addEventListener('load', event => {
  // image ready
});
```

But seemingly you don't need to listen to the 'load' event when setting a `HTMLImageElement`'s `src` property to a dataURL(base64).

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = base64;
// image ready
```

Is setting a `HTMLImageElement`'s `src` property to a base64 value synchronous or just really fast? Is this safe?

Comment: Even if it was async, it wouldn't matter how fast it was because the lines following the assignment would get to execute first anyway. The current executing code always has priority over any async code.